# Is this normal? STM32 CAN module generates an error when waking up

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I put a STM32F205xx to sleep including CAN module. I configure it so that the MC wakes up at any CAN activity.Works fine! There is only one thing that gives me a headache.

When the STM32 wakes up, the first message received is first answered with a NAK. Only the first repetition is answered with an ACK [ARQ] *(only if the two devices are alone on the bus)*.

Is this normal? Is this because of the 11 recessive bits for the SYNC? Or do I have to search for a bug in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When weird stuff like this happens, always check the silicon errata. Can save you lots of time in case it's a known problem.

Comment: I checked this. Nothing mentioned, but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer is pretty simple: NO

No, it's not normal for this to happen. The MC simply wakes up too slowly (9 µs). Then it has already missed the first bits of the message. Only with the repetition, the bxCAN module recognizes the message.

This is not a problem if the MC is alone with the transmitter on the bus. It only becomes a problem if there is another station on the bus, which then signs off the message with an ACK. Thus, the microcontroller simply misses the message.

Reasons can be Ramp Up Time etc.